# Join subquery temp table to query table

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I need to join a single column table generated by a subquery as the last column of the table generated by the parent query.

```
SELECT tn.teamtext, sum(case when CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt,
    (SELECT sum(case when CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' then 1 else 0 end)
      FROM teamnames AS tn 
        JOIN caseaudit AS ca
        ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
      WHERE ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2
      AND isactive = 1
      AND groupid = 18
      AND accountid = 2) AS cnt2
  FROM teamnames AS tn 
    JOIN caseaudit AS ca
    ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
  WHERE ca.referteamid1 <= 0
  AND ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2
  AND isactive = 1
  AND groupid = 18
  AND accountid = 2
  GROUP BY tn.teamtext
  ORDER BY tn.teamtext
```

Gives me:

```
4H BOSS                   55    430
4H BSG                     0    430
4H SALES AND MKTG          0    430
ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE        0    430
ASSET MANAGEMENT           9    430
AUDIT                      0    430
BOSS                       4    430
CORPORATE BSG              0    430
CUSTOMER SUPPORT          87    430
NETWORK ENGINEERING       11    430
PRODUCTION ENGINEERING   116    430
PRODUCTION OPERATIONS      0    430
SECURITY                   2    430
SNFAL PRODUCT TEAM         0    430
VOICE SERVICES            18    430
XEROX                      4    430
```

The '430' is 100% incorrect.

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: what should it be? what is the source data?  this is not really yet a question

Comment: Is the subquery supposed to omit the `ca.referteamid1 <= 0` condition?

Comment: Yes Neil. That is the only difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
SELECT a.teamtext, a.cnt, b.cnt2
FROM

(SELECT tn.teamtext, tn.teamid, sum(case when CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt
 FROM teamnames as tn
    LEFT OUTER JOIN caseaudit AS ca
    ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
 WHERE ca.referteamid1 <= 0 AND ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 AND isactive = 1 AND groupid = 18 AND accountid = 2
 GROUP BY tn.teamtext, tn.teamid) AS a

LEFT OUTER JOIN

 (SELECT tn.teamtext, tn.teamid, sum(case when CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt2
  FROM teamnames AS tn 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN caseaudit AS ca
    ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
  WHERE ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 AND isactive = 1 AND groupid = 18 AND accountid = 2
  GROUP BY tn.teamtext, tn.teamid) AS b
ON a.teamid = b.teamid
ORDER BY a.teamtext
```

Comment: That will work as well but you don't need it to be a `left join` since anything that would be in `a` will always be in `b` due to the where clauses

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the total count along side a Grouped count. Just use an inline query in the FROM CLAUSE and CROSS JOIN to it.

```
SELECT tn.teamtext, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, dModLast, 101) BETWEEN 
                  '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS cnt, 
       t.TotalCnt 
FROM   teamnames AS tn 
       JOIN caseaudit AS ca 
         ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Sum(CASE 
                                WHEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, dModLast, 101) 
                                     BETWEEN 
                                     '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                              END) AS TotalCnt 
                   FROM   teamnames AS tn 
                          JOIN caseaudit AS ca 
                            ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2 
                   WHERE  ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 
                          AND isactive = 1 
                          AND groupid = 18 
                          AND accountid = 2) t 
WHERE  ca.referteamid1 <= 0 
       AND ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 
       AND isactive = 1 
       AND groupid = 18 
       AND accountid = 2 
GROUP  BY tn.teamtext , t.TotalCnt 
ORDER  BY tn.teamtext
```

[Simplified Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fd94/4)

Of course if all you want is TeamText per team text  and the total count you can

- drop the group by
- Add distinct
- Use SUM(Case ..) OVER(Parition  by teamtext) for per teamtext
- Use SUM(Case ..) OVER(Parition  by null) for grand total
- Move `ca.referteamid1 <= 0` into the first SUM.. OVER

```
 SELECT DISTINCT tn.teamtext, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, dModLast, 101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' AND ca.referteamid1 <= 0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY tn.teamtext) AS cnt, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, dModLast, 101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10'  THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS Totalcnt

FROM   teamnames AS tn 
       JOIN caseaudit AS ca 
         ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2 
WHERE 
        ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 
       AND isactive = 1 
       AND groupid = 18 
       AND accountid = 2 
ORDER  BY tn.teamtext
```

[Simplified demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fd94/2)

Comment: I tried running your first suggestion and got an error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 't.TotalCnt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I came up with a more readable solution (in my opinion) by using temp tables. See answer below.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I forgot to include t.TotalCnt in the group by. I've fixed that